# Realm and getter not associated to a field

Tags: android, realm

Why can I create a getter which is not associated to a field when using Realm? For instance I have the following code:

```
public class Profile extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private Contact contact;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contact.getName();
    }
}
```

Why do I get an: Getter is not associated to any field? Is it forbidden to create get methods without a field in Realm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create an `Model`, your class must extends `RealmObject`.

Comment: I had forgotten the RealmObject in my example, thank you. The problem is that I need a getter that doesn't have a field, is it possible with realm?

Comment: Yes, as @Chrisian Melchior said, you can use `Ignore` annotation.

Comment: Thank you, but as I answered, I don't want to create an useless field, as this field would never be used, I just want to create a get method

Comment: @FVod: I'm not sure, but i think:
- First, you can change accessor to public/package private, so you can access from anywhere on your project. (Almost ORM use this)
- Or we need to create getter/setter, just because it is Realm will look and call it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things wrong with that model class.

1) It should extend `RealmObject` not `Realm`.
2) You need to have matching getters and setters for all fields: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models

```
public class Profile extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private Contact contact;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had forgotten the RealmObject in my example, thank you. That was just a simplified example, my problem is that I need a getter that doesn't have a field, is it possible with realm?

Comment: Yes, you can use the @Ignore annotation: view-source:https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#why-do-i-need-to-have-getters-and-setters-for-all-my-fields

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but @ignore annotation implies creating a field in my class. And I don't want to create a field as this is useless, the field will never be used, I just want to create a get method without having to create a field. Is it impossible to achieve with Realm?